# Hola Alguien me puede Explicar como funciona éste código ??? No logro entender

Tags: python-3.x, lista, funciones, modal

**Hola Alguien me puede Explicar. Como funciona éste código ??? No logro entender.

> > > Crear una función que al recibir una lista de números, devuelva el que más se repite y cuántas veces lo hace. Si hay más de un "más repetido", que devuelva cualquiera. es para entender como funciona,

````
    lista_unicos = []
    lista_repeticiones = []
    if len(lista) == 0:
        return None
    for e in lista:
        if e in lista_unicos:
            i = lista_unicos.index(e)
            lista_repeticiones[i] += 1
        else:
            lista_unicos.append(e)
            lista_repeticiones.append(1)
    moda = lista_unicos[0]
    maximo = lista_repeticiones[0]
    for i, e in enumerate(lista_unicos):
        if lista_repeticiones[i] > maximo:
            moda = lista_unicos[i]
            maximo = lista ```
````

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica qué y qué no estás entendiendo del código. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es crear las dos listas que llevaran la cuenta

```
lista_unicos = []
lista_repeticiones = []
```

En `lista_unicos` almacenas los valores encontrados (`[11, 32, 45, 86]`) y en `lista_repeticiones` llevas la cuenta de cuantas veces aparece cada valor. Entonces, `lista_repeticiones` igual a `[3, 1, 2, 7]` dice que el valor 11 aparece 3 veces; el valor 32, 1 vez, etc.

Con esto se valida que la lista tenga al menos un elemento

```
if len(lista) == 0:
    return None
```

Ahora recorremos la lista de entrada. Por cada elemento hay que determinar primero si ya aparecio o no:

```
for e in lista:
    if e in lista_unicos:
```

Si ya está aparecio, uso `index()` para saber su posición en la lista y asi saber donde incrementar el contador.

```
        i = lista_unicos.index(e)
        lista_repeticiones[i] += 1
```

Si el valor aparece por primera vez, tengo que agregarlo a la lista de únicos e inicializar en 1 el contador correspondendiente.

```
    else:
        lista_unicos.append(e)
        lista_repeticiones.append(1)
```

Ya terminado de procesar la lista de entrada, hay que buscar el valor con el máximo número de ocurrencias. `moda` es el valor y `maximo` es la cantidad de ocurrencias que tiene. Para partir, asumimos que el primer elemento es el más frecuente:

```
moda = lista_unicos[0]
maximo = lista_repeticiones[0]
```

Este código recorre la lista de únicos. Por cada valor, mira la cuenta para saber si ocurre más veces que el máximo anterior. En tal cambia el máximo

El código original es incorrecto; lo reescribi así:

```
for i in range(len(lista_unicos)):
    if lista_repeticiones[i] > maximo:
        moda = lista_unicos[i]
        maximo = lista_repeticiones[i]
```

#### Demo

```
def maxrep(lista):
    lista_unicos = []
    lista_repeticiones = []

    if len(lista) == 0:
        return None

    for e in lista:
        if e in lista_unicos:
            i = lista_unicos.index(e)
            lista_repeticiones[i] += 1
        else:
            lista_unicos.append(e)
            lista_repeticiones.append(1)

    moda = lista_unicos[0]
    maximo = lista_repeticiones[0]

    for i in range(len(lista_unicos)):
        if lista_repeticiones[i] > maximo:
            moda = lista_unicos[i]
            maximo = lista_repeticiones[i]

    return moda, maximo

moda, maximo = maxrep([1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7])
print(moda, maximo)
```

produce:

```
2 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```